# Converting R formula to string and then manipulating it

Tags: r, string

```
exposure <- 'B'
outcome <- 'A'
```

I have a formula that looks like this in R

```
form <- formula(A ~ B + C + D)
```

I want to convert it to a string like this where I remove the exposure and the outcome

```
C + D
```

How can i do this in R?

Comment: Yes sorry! updated.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this helps

```
reformulate(setdiff(all.vars(form), c(exposure, outcome)))
~C + D
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
form_str <- as.character(form)
[1] "~"         "A"         "B + C + D"
variables <- strsplit(form_str[3], " + ", fixed = TRUE)[[1]]
[1] "B" "C" "D"
paste(setdiff(variables, exposure), collapse = " + ")
"C + D"
```